# Suppress extraction of __MACOSX directory when unzipping

Tags: linux, command-line, zip, archiving

ZIP archives produced on Mac OS X systems usually include a `__MACOSX` directory which is [useless, annoying, and unwanted](https://superuser.com/a/364124/142252) on pretty much every other OS.

For unpacking ZIP archives I use [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/), which I think is the default unzipper on most Linux distributions.  What's the best way of having Info-ZIP's `unzip` always and automatically suppress the extraction of any `__MACOSX` directory which may be present?

According to the `unzip` man page, the `-x` option can be used to exclude directories from processing, and indeed adding `-x __MACOSX/*` to the end of my `unzip` command line does the trick.  But I don't want to have to type this all the time.  The man page also says that command-line options can be read from the `UNZIP` environment variable, but apparently this works only for those options which come *before* the archive name (whereas `-x` must come after it):

```
$ export UNZIP="-x __MACOSX/*"
$ unzip foo.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open __MACOSX, __MACOSX.zip or __MACOSX.ZIP.
```

Is there any better solution than wrapping `unzip` in a shell script which automatically adds `-x __MACOSX/*` to the end of the command line?

Answer (score 12):

Use a shell function:

```
myunzip() {
    unzip "$@" -x '__MACOSX/*'
}

myunzip foo.zip
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you! However, I modified mine: my function is called `unzip`, it calls `/usr/bin/unzip` and the first argument is `$@`. That way, my habit of calling `unzip` remains untouched and `$@` does proper escaping of arguments. I don't know what `"@$"` does.

Comment: It was a typo for `$@`.