# Why does a USB drive has a "Mac_OSX" folder when I use it on a Mac and then open it on a PC?

Tags: windows, macos, desktop-computer

Just curious as to why a folder named "Mac OSX" shows up on a USB drive / Folder after being used on a mac?

Comment: Because it does things to it. If you look into that folder you should see some files. If I'm not mistaken it's analogues to the `thumbs.db` files windows creates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is \_\_MACOSX folder?](http://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is answered quite thoroughly in this thread:-

[Link to "What-is-macosxfolder" discussion on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder)

To summarise, it is a folder that the Mac uses to hold meta data/resource fork information.  It is hidden on the Mac but Windows displays it as a normal folder, much like the DS_Store files that can be left on Windows Network shares for Windows users to see if you browse the shares using a Mac.

Comment: Please don't link to another question that answers this one. The correct thing to do is to flag/vote to close as a duplicate.